# Background image turns out blurry

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a background image to a grid item, but regardless of which browser I use, the image always turns out blurry. The original dimensions of the photo are 6000 x 4000. Here is the code that I used for the grid:

```
.content {
 grid-area: content;
 padding-top: 15%;
 background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=14rw1Bbhf5MWV3BlBx3G0tVzmoUcK03I6");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

This is the original image:
[image]

And this is what the image looks like from the webpage (ignore the text):
[image]

I've also tried converting the image to .svg or .eps, but that just makes the picture turn out even worse. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Without more information this will be difficult to solve. Could it be that you upload the image in a cms (wordpress, joomla, ...)? Does the html code contain a [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images). Is the image path the same as the original?

Comment: Yes, the image paths are the same (there's only one), and there's no html code related to the image. I currently have the photo stored in my google drive.

Comment: You appear to be picking up the thumbnail of a much larger image. Put the original image into the background not the thumbnail version.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The only reason I shrunk the picture in this post is because there's a size limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not big enough to be shown on full screen and that's why its blurry. I have copied the original image link you have pasted in your question and updated the `.content` class. Use this and set the `height: 100vh`:

```
   .content {
        grid-area: content;
        padding-top: 15%;
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkpSw.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding the edits, but it still looks blurry. I'd say the only change that I can see is that the full height of the image can be seen in the screen.

Comment: Take a look at this CodePen: https://codepen.io/khan9920/pen/NWgOJZL

Blur issue is fixed just by adding higer resolution image. The image you use from your Google drive is 220x147. The image I have used is 1125x750

Comment: The picture that I'm using has a resolution of 6000 x 4000. I had to shrink it down to add it to this post, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different image host. The Problem seems to bee with Google Drive & not with your code. The image sent by Google Drive is already compressed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be picking up the thumbnail version of the image which is of course much smaller and so when you ask it to cover the page it gets blurry.

It seems as though the original large version with the dimensions you mention can be picked up like this:

```css
.content {
  grid-area: content;
  padding-top: 15%;
  background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=14rw1Bbhf5MWV3BlBx3G0tVzmoUcK03I6");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.inner {
  /* just to give some content for this demo */
  height: 100vh;
  display: inliine-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

But you probably don't want such a large file for normal browser use - perhaps get an intermediate size and store it yourself?

Note, the image is in focus in the foreground, but even on this very large size it looks a bit burry at the top of the parachute - that is just what the image is.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to yours, I solved it by changing the background size

instead of

```
background-size: cover;
```

I used

```
background-size: 100% 400px;
```

You can play around with that to get your desired outcome, worked for me I hope it works for you aswell!